# issue changing hidden input value from popup form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

The best way to show what I am trying to do is show a demo. I will provide my jsfiddle in a sec.

The table displays 3 tests, one of the tests is password protected (Test 3). So on clicking to execute that test, you get a form pop up requesting you enter a password. Currently on the jsfiddle I have inputs named 'password' set as `type=text` these will be `hidden`, currently just showing them for test.

On submitting the password I want the 'password' input to be filled with the input, however for the corresponding test and submit that corresponding form (each test is a form essentially). At the moment it just fills all of the password inputs with the password inputted.

**EDIT** updated my jsfiddle to rid of duplicate id problem.

So here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6JFv/16/).

What is the best way I can identify the particular forms input to fill with the value inputted?

I hope I have been clear enough :S

thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same ID more than once. A simple fix would be to call your three password fields "password1", "password2" and "password3", like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/mHdwz/2/

but that may not be the best fix depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: if you look at my update. I have changed it so it appends to the password input by class. Problem is it obviously changes all of them. I just want it to change the right one lol.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to save the jsfiddle. Look again.

Comment: ye but my page is far more dynamic than that, I don't know how many tests there will be etc with password protection. So I need to be able to identify which form the new form sprung from essentially, so I can identify which password input to change.

Comment: the static html, is just for demo purpose. its all filled from a database actually in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
//WHEN THEY SUBMIT PASSWORD CARRY THIS OUT
$(".pass_submit").live('click', function(event) {
    var plaintext = $('#pass').val();
    $(this).parents('form').children('.password').val(plaintext);
});
```